# Combine detail and delete views ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, actionresult

I currently have separate views and controller actions for my details and delete methods. I would like to place the delete button on the details view so a user doesn't have to click delete, then delete again on they are on the delete view. I have this most of the way by not having a "get" delete method and using an ajax.actionlink helper within the details view to call the post method:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", 
    new { id = Model.DepartmentId }, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId="output", Confirm= "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" }, 
    new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
```

The only problem is when the delete is successful, I want to redirect to a search view. Currently, my delete controller "post" method is as follows:

```
//
// POST: /Department/Delete/5
[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(DepartmentViewModel vmNotUsed, int id = 0)
{
    if (id != 0)
    {
        // check to see if the department item is associated with an asset assignment
        bool InUseByAssetAssignment = AssetAssignmentService.ValueInUse(x => x.DepartmentId == id);

        if (InUseByAssetAssignment == false)
        {
            DepartmentService.DeleteDepartment(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Search");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("<p style='color:#f00';>This department cannot be deleted because there are items associated with it.</p>");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("You must select a Department to delete!");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it returns the view INSIDE of the current details view:

[image]

I don't know if this makes sense or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your request is AJAX based, you need to return javascript to perform the redirect - something like:

```
return JavaScript(string.format("window.location = '{0}'", Url.Action("Search")));
```

Should do what you are asking.